# Flatten table hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to transform a table like this:

```
Parent  Child   Value
1       Color   Red
1       Height  11
1       Width   12
1       Length  11
2       Color   Blue
2       Height  10
2       Width   2
2       Length  5
```

Into this:

```
Parent  Color   Height  Width   Length
1       Red     11      12      11
2       Blue    10      2       5
```

The child attributes could change at anytime so having the converted columns dynamically built would be best.

Comment: there are countless questions and answers about this in SO, just search for sql-server and dynamic pivot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to transpose the rows to column

```
select Parent,
max(case when Child='Color' then Value End) 'Color',
max(case when Child='Height' then Value End) 'Height',
max(case when Child='Width' then Value End) 'Width',
max(case when Child='Length' then Value End) 'Length'
from yourtable
group by Parent
```

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this, it looks perfectly acceptable to me.  `PIVOT` works also, though it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, This is absolutely right, +1 from my side.